# Cocos3d : Set CC3Scene backdrop to transparent

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

In one of the `ViewController` of my app I have added a `CCGLView`, on top of which I'm adding `CC3Layer` to show the model and animate it. I want the background of the `CCGLView` to be transparent, but I'm unable to set the backdrop color of `CC3Scene` to transparent and by default if backdrop node isn't added the background color is black. And I have set CCGLView's backgroundColor to [UIColor clearColor] but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to know how to do it, we just have to set backdrop node to following:

```
    self.backdrop = [CC3Backdrop nodeWithColor:ccc4f(0.0/255.0, 0.0/255.0, 0.0/255.0, 0.0)];
```

Thats all, the `CC3Scene` background become's transparent.